# Passing in a Bitmap as the EXTRA_STREAM parameter when launching an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

From the JavaDoc, the EXTRA_STREAM parameter when launching an intent needs to be an URI. 
How can I pass a Bitmap object which I get from launching a "android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE" intent?

```
/**
     * A content: URI holding a stream of data associated with the Intent,
     * used with {@link #ACTION_SEND} to supply the data being sent.
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_STREAM = "android.intent.extra.STREAM";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to save it to disk and pass a `file:` URI in the `EXTRA_STREAM` extra.